# Adding html object inside another html object

Tags: jquery, html, css, dom

before I start I wanted to tell you maybe my tongue is not enough to understand each other that is why I'm sorry.

I have html codes which are the below;

```
  <div class="container">
     <div class="column">
         <input type="text">
     </div>
 </div>
```

and I wrapped my input object with jquery for example;

```
$(".column").wrapAll("<div class='row'><div class='col-md-6'></div></div>");
```

and my html document is being like this;

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="column">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-6">
         <input type="text">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

but real problem I couldn't solve is exactly here, after that I couldn't add any html object with jquery for example I want to add before .col-md-6 class

```
<div class="col-md-2">Name Lastname</div>
```

but it's not happening neither insertBefore(); nor jquery dom insertion. do you mind if I ask about problem ?

Comment: Please share some code and reproduce your problem in a fiddle

Comment: Is working fine here: https://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/dq4L6mk1/

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you're trying to do: https://jsfiddle.net/yo031jcs/1/

jQuery:

```
$(".column").prepend("<div class='col-md-2'>Name Lastname</div>");
$(".column").wrapAll("<div class='row'><div class='col-md-6'></div></div>");
```

jQuery documentation: http://api.jquery.com/prepend/

EDIT: here's an updated fiddle so the col-md-2 goes inside the row: https://jsfiddle.net/yo031jcs/2/

Updated jQuery:

```
$(".column").wrapAll("<div class='row'><div class='col-md-6'></div></div>");
$(".row").prepend("<div class='col-md-2'>Name Lastname</div>");
```

Comment: I was literally typing this up when I saw you post this.

Comment: but it's adding outside of row

Comment: @yedincifirat Here's an updated fiddle: [https://jsfiddle.net/yo031jcs/2/](https://jsfiddle.net/yo031jcs/2/)

Comment: @yedincifirat, did you check the revised fiddle? If it answers your question, please mark answer as correct...

Answer (score 0):

Its working without any error. Please have a look at this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".column").wrapAll("<div class='row'><div class='col-md-6'></div></div>");
  $("<div class='col-md-2'>Name Lastname</div>").insertBefore(".col-md-6")
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div class="container">
     <div class="column">
         <input type="text">
     </div>
 </div>
```